# Programmatically stop decreasing stock qty while placing an order in magento and increaging qty when order state is Compleate

Tags: php, stock, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9.0.1 by default, it decreases stock qty while placing an order. I want to stop decreasing stock qty while placing an order for the purpose of fake order. And I also want the functionality of increasing stock qty while order state is complete, not pending, not processing. How to do it programmatically or by setting up in Admin panel. If any one knows about it, please reply back.

Thank You
 Ankan

Answer (score 0):

Just simply open your admin panel, go to System->Configuration->Catalog Tab->Inventory Then click on Stack Option and change Decrease Stock When Order is Placed to NO.

Thanks,
Lovekesh

Answer (score 0):

In Admin panel, System->Configuration->Catalog Tab->Inventory Then click on Stack Option and change Decrease Stock When Order is Placed to NO. So that it stops the stock qty increasing.In Model/Automatically/Complete/Order/Observer.php page,    class Webspidy_Customoption_Model_Automatically_Complete_Order_Observer
{ public function __construct(){} 
public function automaticallycompleteorder($observer)
    {
        //Mage::log('Ankan');
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        /*$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));*/

```
    /*if ((int)$orders->count() !== 0) {
        return $this;
    }*/

    //Mage::log($orderstate);

    //if($order->getState() == 'complete'){
    if(($order->getState() == 'processing') || ($order->getState() == 'pending_payment')){
        if($order->hasInvoices()){  
    //Mage::log($orderstate);
        //Mage::log('Ankan');
        //Mage::log($order->getData());
        //====== Order Details ================
        $orderNumber = $order->getIncrementId();  //Mage::log($orderNumber);
        $orderDet = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderNumber, 'increment_id');
          //Mage::log($orderDet->getData());
        $orderItems = $orderDet->getItemsCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

        foreach($orderItems as $orderItem){ 
            $productId = $orderItem->getProductId();
            $productOptionSku   = $orderItem->getSku();
            $productQty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $centralqty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();

            $values = array();
            foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
               $p = $o->getValues();
            }
            foreach($p as $v)
            {
                $optionSku = $v->getSku();
                $optionItem = $v->getQty();

                //Mage::log($optionItem);
                //Mage::log($productOptionSku.".....".$sku."-".$optionSku.".....".$optionItem);

                if($productOptionSku == ($sku."-".$optionSku)){

                    if($centralqty >= ($optionItem*(int)$productQty)){
                        //$stockQty = (($centralqty-($optionItem*(int)$productQty))+$productQty);
                        $stockQty = ($centralqty-($optionItem*(int)$productQty));
                    }
                }
             }
            $product->save();
            //Mage::log($stockQty); 

            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
            //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->load($productId);
            $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();

            $stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);//(integer)$XMLproduct->QtyInStock
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock',1);


            $stockItem->save(); 

        }
      }
        //======== End ======
    }

}
```

}
And in etc/config.xml,
`<global><events>
  <sales_order_save_after><observers>
<webspidy_customoption_automatically_complete_order_observer>
<type>singleton</type>              <class>Webspidy_Customoption_Model_Automatically_Complete_Order_Observer</class>
<method>automaticallycompleteorder</method>
</webspidy_customoption_automatically_complete_order_observer>
</observers></sales_order_save_after></events></global>` After a long process, I have got a success by creating Observer in my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 1.9

I have tried with the following code. it's OK But i have another smart code

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
$stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
$stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock',1);
$stockItem->save();
```

My code is following:-

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')->backItemQty($productId,$new_qty);
```